# Help on a graph theory question

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose G is an $n$-vertex graph containing no triangle as a subgraph. What is the best
upperbound you can find for $d(u) + d(v)$, where u and v are two different vertices of $G$.
(recall: $d(u)$ means the degree of vertex $u$) .

- I believe the answer is $n$ (the number of vertices)

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.se! Could you explain how you reached your conjecture?

Answer (score 3):

If $u,v$ are neighbours, then each of the other $n-2$ vertices can be connected to at most one of $u,v$. This makes $(d(u)-1)+(d(v)-1)\le n2$, i.e., $d(u)+d(v)\le n$.

If $u,v,$ are not neighbours, then nothing really prevents $u$ and $v$ from both being connected to *all* other $n-2$ vertices. In fact, this happens in the complete bipartite graph $K_{2,n-2}$. Here, $d(u)+d(v)=2n-4$.

We conclude that the best bound when we do not know/specify if $u,v$ are neighbours or not, is
$$ d(u)+d(v)\le\max\{n,2n-4\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Say vertices $u,v$ are connected. Let $N(v)$ be set of neighbour for $v$ and $N(u)$ for $u$.

If $|N(u)\cap N(v)|>0$ then there exist $w$ which is connected to both. A contradiction.

So $|N(u)\cap N(v)|=0$ and thus $$d(u)+d(v) = |N(u)|+|N(v)| = |N(u)\cup N(v)|\leq |V(G)| = n$$

Comment: What if $u$ and $v$ are not connected though?

Comment: I'm not sure why you ask since you can see other answer also. @Mike